# What does the "memory" mean in Memory-based CF?

Tags: collaborative-filtering

The article [Collaborative Filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) says there are two types of CF, memory-based and model-based respectively.

> **Memory-based**
>
> This approach uses user rating data to compute the similarity between users or items. This is used for making recommendations. This was an early approach used in many commercial systems ...

What confuses me is that: What does the `memory` mean here? Do We need fit all data into memory?

Answer (score 1):

Memory based techniques takes the entire database to generate recommendations. It takes all users which are similar to the active user and uses their preferences to base recommendations on.

The problem with this technique is obviously the performance. Especially in real life examples where the database exceeds thousands of users. This makes it very slow, since even in memory, it uses the entire database.

[This](http://www.cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/0607/recommend/recommender/memorybased.html) page might explain it better.

The alternative to memory based is model based. Model based recommendation engines take a little bit of information to create a 'model' to create recommendations. This means it won't have to use the entire database every time. This technique offers more scalability than memory-based.

The same site has [this](http://www.cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/0607/recommend/recommender/modelbased.html) page with more information about this.

Let me know if you need more information!